# How to show the my android apps data on home screen of the android?

Tags: android

Hi i am working on a module now my requirement is like i have to display my apps some data on the home screen of the Android like a clock is shown. 
Similarly like a weather widget shows some data on the Homescreen , similarly i want to show my application some data onto the homescreen.

Can i show some part of the data which will auto update on the home screen. I am not getting the way to do it. I searched on the net for the thing but i am not finding any suitable thing.

My first question is like can it be done and if it can be achieved can u suggest me some references.

Answer (score 1):

They're called App Widgets and the android documentation discusses it to some length here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: can a person from my apps activate the widget so that it appears on the homescreen. Is that possible

Comment: Yes, the same way they add any other widget to the home screen.

Comment: @anand: "can a person from my apps activate the widget so that it appears on the homescreen" -- no. The user adds the app widget to their home screen manually. The user gets to control whether the app widget exists and where on the home screen it goes. You cannot force the user to add your app widget.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hmmm, actually this was my real question and requirement . So there is no way from my apps to give the user a option just set as background kind of thing. So i also want my app users to set the widget onto thier homescreen.

Comment: anything closer to this approach which i can do .. it will be very helpful for me